# Append count after each match

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Sample input:

```
>Sample GJVT7LS03DEUKL
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGC
>Sample GJVT7LS03CXJ53
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGGGG
>Sample GJVT7LS03DJOYJ
AAACTCC
>Sample GJVT7LS03DMERH
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGGGGGGAC
>Sample GJVT7LS03DN2RB
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGG
```

What I want out:

```
>Sample_1 GJVT7LS03DEUKL
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGC
>Sample_2 GJVT7LS03CXJ53
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGGGG
>Sample_3 GJVT7LS03DJOYJ
AAACTCC
>Sample_4 GJVT7LS03DMERH
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGGGGGGAC
>Sample_5 GJVT7LS03DN2RB
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGG
```

In other words, I want to append count (preceded by "_") for each line that matches pattern ("Sample" in this case). Any sed/awk/etc. one-liners for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
$ awk '/^>/{$1=$1"_"++i}1' file
>Sample_1 GJVT7LS03DEUKL
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGC
>Sample_2 GJVT7LS03CXJ53
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGGGG
>Sample_3 GJVT7LS03DJOYJ
AAACTCC
>Sample_4 GJVT7LS03DMERH
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGGGGGGAC
>Sample_5 GJVT7LS03DN2RB
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGG
```

Comment: Note that he is mentioning the `Sample` pattern, not `>`. Nice to learn it was not necessary to initialize i to 1, but just use `++i`.

Comment: Sorry @fedorqui I have prior knowledge of the format ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format This is certainly a job for post increment not pre.

Comment: Uhms @sudo_O, should have guessed it from the GATTACA-way text :)

Comment: ++i is certainly _pre_ increment @sudo_O

Answer (score 2):

One possible attempt is as follows:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a=1}/Sample/ {$1=$1"_"a; a++}1' file
>Sample_1 GJVT7LS03DEUKL
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGC
>Sample_2 GJVT7LS03CXJ53
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGGGG
>Sample_3 GJVT7LS03DJOYJ
AAACTCC
>Sample_4 GJVT7LS03DMERH
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGGGGGGAC
>Sample_5 GJVT7LS03DN2RB
AAACTCCGCAATGCGCGCAAGCGTGACGG
```

For each file containing "Sample" we update the first field with `"_"$variable`. This variable is `a` initially set to 1 and that we then increment in one.